# Call inner class with a button click in main class. Java Applet

Tags: java, class, applet, awt

I am attempting to make a menu, which has 3 options. I want to make each of these options a class. And call that class on a button click. I am having a hard time figuring out how to call inner classes. Could you please help me out?

```
public class menu extends Applet
    {

        public void init(){

        Button playButton = new Button ("Play");
        Button howButton = new Button ("Instructions");
        Button quitButton = new Button ("Quit :(");
        this.add(playButton);
        this.add(howButton);
        this.add(quitButton);

        game gameObject = new game();



        }

        class game extends Applet { 
            //code for this would go here...
        }//game

        }//menu
```

Comment: I strongly recommend having a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm) as AWT is way out of date

Comment: I don't think your `game` class needs to extend `Applet` either, but would probably extend from some other container class (`JPanel` in Swing for example), which could be swapped out for the current content of the applet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would instantiate your inner game class from within the menu class like so:

```
menu.game gameObject = this.new game();
```

For a more elaborate explanation see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

And in addition to the comments above: I would advise you add a proper constructor to the menu class and have that call `init()` (which could then become private). After all you want to do OOP, right?

Comment: It does not work I am afraid. There are no errors but my class is not called.

Comment: @George What do you mean by "is not called"? All that this line does in terms of user code execution is to call the no-argument constructor of your inner class (which does nothing by default). So if you want to see something happening, you should write your own constructor and e.g. shout "Hello World!" from there.